# Is it possible to get the downloaded data of a paused chrome download?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that works with downloads and I was wondering if I can pause a download, and find a file (outside chrome) with a size that is equal to the so far downloaded size shown in chrome. I looked in the default downloads folder and found a file with a `.crdownload` extension but its size is not equal to the value chrome says.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) contains everything the extensions can see so no, it's not possible.

Comment: About the same size here between what Chrome reports and what' on disk int he .crdownload file. How different is it on your system? If it's bigger, chrome probably requested the full size, so your OS may report this instead.

Comment: @wOxxOm it seems OP doesn't even want to read it from their extension, but if they did, isn't [DownloadItem.bytesReceived](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#type-DownloadItem) returning just that?

Comment: "Number of bytes received" isn't the actual bytes...

Comment: @Kaiido I tried a pausing a 2.7GB file, and chrome reported that 1.1GB has been downloaded but the .crdownload file was about 520MB.

Comment: @Kaiido and yes, I read the docs. As wOxxOm said, the .bytesReceived value is not what I want. I want to get the actual downloaded part of the file.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I guess you're right, may not be possible. Thanks

Comment: Until it's fully downloaded the data won't be decompressed, so what you have on disk before it's complete is this "Number of bytes received". What did you try to download, could it be significantly compressed over the network? The reported size probably does an estimation of what it represents.

Comment: Chrome doesn't compress the intermediate file. It just doesn't flush its internal memory buffer while downloading.

Comment: @Kaiido I tried it with a local server, and downloaded a zip file. I doubt if the compression would make that much difference on an already compressed file

Comment: @wOxxOm of course Chrome doesn't, server does. And yes, for such a difference on a zip file it's probably they kept it in memory. (once again on my system there is only a couple MB of difference between their claim and OS's one on a 1GB file paused in the middle.

Comment: My point is that the file on the disk is the actual version of the file without any network compression.

Comment: @wOxxOm are you sure about that? Can they really decompress only a chunk of the compressed data?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The file can be viewed directly (in other apps) while it's being downloaded.